# Erlang OTP UDP Server

Tags: erlang, udp

Here is a simple UDP server:

```
-module(kvstore_udpserver).
-author("mylesmcdonnell").

%% API
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
  spawn(fun() -> server(2346) end).

server(Port) ->
  {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary]),
  loop(Socket).

loop(Socket) ->
  receive
    {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Bin} ->
      case binary_to_term(Bin) of
        {store, Value} ->
          io:format("kvstore_udpserver:{store, Value}~n"),
          gen_udp:send(Socket,Host,Port,term_to_binary(kvstore:store(Value)));
        {retrieve, Key} ->
          io:format("kvstore_udpserver:{retrieve, Value}~n"),
          gen_udp:send(Socket,Host,Port,term_to_binary(kvstore:retrieve(Key)))
      end,
      loop(Socket)
  end.
```

How can I restructure this so that

a) It, or at least the relevant part of it, is a gen_server so that I can add to the supervision tree

b) increase concurrency by handling each message in a separate process.

I have reimplemented the sockserv example from Learn You Some Erlang for my TCP server but I'm struggling to determine a similar model for UDP.

Answer (score 4):

For a):

1. You need to delcare the `gen_server` behaviour and implement all the callback functions (this is obvious, but it's worth calling out explicitly).  If you have `rebar` installed, you can use the command `rebar create template=simplesrv srvid=your_server_name` to add the boilerplate functions.
2. You'd probably want to move the server starting business logic (the `gen_udp:open/2` call) to your server's `init/1` function. (The init is required by the `gen_server` behaviour.  You can also start your `loop/1` function there.
3. You'd probably want to make sure the udp server is closed by the module's `terminate/2` function.
4. Move the business logic for handling requests that come in from parsing the messages to your `loop/1` function into `handle_call/3` or `handle_cast/2` in your module (see below).

For b):
You have a few options, but basically, whenever you receive a message, you can use `gen_server:cast/2` (if you don't care about the response) or `gen_server:call/2,3` if you do.  The casts or calls will be handled by the `handle_cast/2` or `handle_call/3` functions in your module.

Casts are inherently non-blocking and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031910/otp-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-messaging) have a good design pattern for handling call operations asynchronously in `gen_servers`.  You can crib from that.